# BISON+FLEX using short form of tokens

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I'd like to implement some command lang ...
Is there a way to implement token reconginizing to get token for "CREATE" :

```
CREATE  
CRE
CREA
CREAT
```

another example:

```
DELE
DEL
DELET
DELETE
```

for token "DELETE"

I know way like :

```
"CREATE" { return KWD_CREATE;}
"CRE"    { return KWD_CREATE;}


"DEL"     { return KWD_DELETE;}
"DELET"   { return KWD_DELETE;}
```

**But, is there a right way to recognize reduced form of keywords ?**

Update: I have tried the suggested trick like:

```
CRE(A(T(E?)?)?   { return KWD_CREATE;}
DEL(E(T(E?)?)?   { return KWD_DELETE;}
```

But next problem is take place:

```
CREATE - is recognized
CREAT - is recognized
CREA - is **not** recognized
```

I see "syntax error, unexpected **id**", **id** it's **identifier** pattern as follow:

```
identifier  [$_a-zA-Z][$_a-zA-Z0-9\%\*]*
```

Any idea? What's im need to check additionaly ?

Thanks!

Comment: Didn't that pattern give you an error when you ran it through flex? By the way, inside character classes (`[...]`), you don't need to backslash-escape regex characters. None of them are special except the backslash itself, and `-` and `]`. (Outside of character classes, `-` and `]` are not special and do not need to be escaped.)

Comment: Ok. Let me check only FLEX part of the parser (w/o BISON). Thanks again!

Comment: I meant the pattern with an unbalanced parenthesis (before I fixed it). When I passed it through flex, it gave me an "unrecognized rule" error, which made the typo obvious. I was just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no shorthand for this syntax, but you can simply use, for example:

```
CRE(A(TE?)?)?   { return KWD_CREATE;}
DEL(E(TE?)?)?   { return KWD_DELETE;}
```

That would be easy enough to do programmatically if you were generating your lexer with some kind of generator-generator (a technique I find quite useful).

Test:

```
$ cat abbrev.l
%option noinput nounput noyywrap nodefault 8bit
%%
cre(a(te?)?)?   { fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "CREATE"); }
del(e(te?)?)?   { fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "DELETE"); }
[[:alpha:]]+    { fprintf(stderr, "WORD: %s\n", yytext); }
[[:space:]]+    ;
.               { fprintf(stderr, "PUNC: %c\n", *yytext); }
$ flex -o abbrev.c abbrev.l
$ gcc -Wall -o abbrev abbrev.c -lfl
$ ./abbrev
create
CREATE
creat
CREATE
crea
CREATE
cre
CREATE
cr
WORD: cr
delete
DELETE
delet
DELETE
dele
DELETE
del
DELETE
de
WORD: de
```

Comment: Just tried. "create" -  ok, "creat" - ok, "crea" - error . It's looks like that FLEX is expect  more characters to recognize pattern. Any ideas ?

Comment: @Ruslan: Sorry, there was a stray open parenthesis in those patterns. I fixed it, and tested. I'll add the test code.

Comment: No problemo!  I corrected the pattern. Thanks for u help!